# syntax error at or near "=@" when using parameters

Tags: dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to update/insert data to postgresql depending whether given id is already preset in the table.

This works for update

```
UPDATE table SET 
   column=@Column
WHERE id=@Id;
```

And this works also (hardcoded values)

```
DO 
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=123) THEN
 UPDATE table SET 
    column=123
 WHERE id=123;
ELSE
 INSERT INTO table(id,column) VALUES (123,123);
END IF;
END
$$
```

But as soon as I try to give values as parameters, it breaks giving an error **syntax error at or near "=@"**

```
DO 
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=@Id) THEN
 UPDATE table SET 
    column=@Column
 WHERE id=@Id;
ELSE
 INSERT INTO table(id,column) VALUES (@Id,@Column);
END IF;
END
$$
```

To isolate the problem leaving just one parameter like this

```
DO 
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=@Id) THEN
 UPDATE table SET 
    column=123
 WHERE id=123;
ELSE
 INSERT INTO table(id,column) VALUES (123,123);
END IF;
END
$$
```

Gives error is **Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: column "id" does not exist'**. So is there some kind of magic I have to do with the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npgsql does not support parameters within dollar-quoted string literals ($$).

However, you seem to be implementing upsert (update or insert) - PostgreSQL supports that natively with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` syntax. See [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) or other documentation on this feature, which should obviate the complexity of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately postgre version might be lower than 9.5 so I couldn't use that.

Comment: In theory you could simply define a function (CREATE FUNCTION) once, and then execute that. But doing that is faulty, just like your code above - in a concurrent environment there's a race condition where a row could be added by someone else after you do the check, but before you INSERT. So not the right approach...